# Create a passable variable from JRadioButtonMenuItem in java

Tags: java, swing

I just started working with Java this semester and I am now working on a group project.  I have created the drop down menu but now I need to take the options the user chooses and pass them to another class. I've tried using an `ActionListener` (you'll see commented out), but then I figured I didn't really need it because it was radiobuttons and I could use `.isSelected()` instead.

Can you help me to understand what is going on and how I should proceed to be able to do the intended variable passing? Thank you in advance. Please see code below:

```
public class GameMenu extends JFrame
{   
    String animal;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem dog; 
    JRadioButtonMenuItem cat;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenu animalOptions;

    public GameMenu()
    {
        setTitle("The Most Fun Game Ever");
        setSize(800, 800);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Adds menubar to the JFrame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        //Define and add drop down menu to menubar  
        menu = new JMenu("Game Options");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        //Create and add radio button items and set their accelerators
        dog = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Dog");
        cat = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Cat");

        //Define each button group and add items to each group.
        ButtonGroup animalGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        animalGroup.add(dog);
        animalGroup.add(cat);

        //Define 4 submenus for the main menu items & set Mnemonics
        animalOptions = new JMenu("Animal Options");

        //Add items to the submenus
        animalOptions.add(dog);
        animalOptions.add(cat);

        //Add a listener to the menu items
        //dog.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        //{
        //    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        //    {
        //        animal = "tiger-dog.jpg";
        //    }
        //});
    }

    public String getAnimal()
    {
        if (dog.isSelected())
        {
            animal = "tiger-dog.jpg";
        }

        else if (cat.isSelected())
        {
            animal = "bruteforce-cat.jpg";
        }

        return animal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GameMenu test = new GameMenu();
        String animalChoice = test.getAnimal();
        System.out.println(animalChoice);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please strip the code down to only include the relevant part; its very hard to comprehend this way.

Comment: Here you @AndreasWolf.  Sorry about that.

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `public String getAnimal(animal)` the parameter has no type

Comment: I took that out.  I've manipulated this code so many times.  I accidentally pasted that in there.  Thanks D.B.

Comment: Sadly I think this question is probably not specific enough to give a good answer - there are many ways you could implement a solution. I'd suggest you read about the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and try to stick to that as close as you can. Also, you seem to already have a "passable variable" being returned by the getAnimal method. If you could provide more info about what it is you're trying to accomplish it would help others to answer.

Comment: Thanks D.B.  I appreciate your time.  I will take a look at that page and see what I can figure out.  I may need to adjust my "view" of this problem and try a different approach.